# Height in Object mode does not match the height in edit mode?

Tags: units

I wanted to simply create a cylinder with height of 1cm and a radius of 10cm. So I set the corresponding scales in the toolbar:  [image]

After that I went into edit mode, I enabled the edge length overlay and selected an edge from the bottom to the top:

[image]

I expected that it would be 1cm long (which is what I typed in object mode), but it is 20 cm. I also noticed the "Scale" entries in the toolbar in object mode. If you multiply 20cm by 0.005 you would arrive at 0.1cm which does not make any sense.

What's going on? Is this a bug? I tried this in version 2.83.15 and 2.93.0 same behavior.

Comment: Hello, it looks right to me : It's 200cm, not 20cm. 200 * 0.005 = 1 cm. Go to object > Apply > Scale or CTRL A > Scale to get the same dimensions

Comment: Ah I was not aware of the fact that you have to apply transformations! That's the answer, thanks! Add it as answer and I will accept it.